# c# run encrypted dtsx package

Tags: c#, encryption, ssis

```
// encrypted file path
    string source = @"C:\Users\cfa\Desktop\encryptedPackage.dtsx";

    // decrypted file destination
    destination = @"C:\Users\cfa\Desktop\test\decryptedPackage.dtsx";

    // read encrypted file
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(source);

    // decrypted file
    decrypted = crypt.Decryption(text);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(destination, decrypted);

    // run decrypted dtsx file - destination
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
    Package package = app.LoadPackage(destination, null);
    DTSExecResult pkgResults;
    pkgResults = package.Execute();

    // delete destination file
    File.Delete(destination);
```

With the previous code, i´m running an encrypted dtsx package.
I run the decryption method and save the result to a destination file and execute that file.
Is there a way to run the package without creating a destinations file?

Comment: We're missing some code. `crypt` is an instance of what class? Has this package been encrypted outside of the native package encryption available to SSIS?

Comment: @billinkc  Descryption is the method created inside the class crypt to decrypt the .dtsx file. it returns the decrypted contents of the dtsx file in the form of a string, which is saved to the destination file. I was wondering if there is a way to run the file as a string instead of loading the destination. something like 'Package package = app.LoadPackage(decrypted, null);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand the request, in memory you have the XML version of a package and you wish to save the cost of writing the unencrypted bits to disk just to run. The approach of using the [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application_methods.aspx) class to instantiate isn't going to work as there isn't a method that accepts a stream. It needs to pull from disk, from a SQL Server table or the package store.

Instead, the Package class has a [LoadFromXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190828.aspx) method which should be what you're looking for.

Code then becomes

```
Package package = package.LoadFromXML(decrypted, null);
```